# Arduino Nano Er.43

Tags: arduino-nano, clones

I am using an Arduino Nano clone on Windows 10. Worked perfectly fine for a year until I uploaded a code with some Serial functions. After trouble shooting for hours with drivers, and checking all over the internet, I come to the conclusion that the last code uploaded was faulty and corrupted the Serial interface. Every time I plug it in now, Windows gives a popup saying "USB Device Not Recognized."

I have checked for shorts all over the board, but none found, and the indicating lights are working fine. From what I have read, I believe that the board is still recoverable.

How to get it working?

The link to the board purchased: [Mini USB Nano V3.0 ATmega328P CH340G 5V 16M Micro-Controller Board for Arduino Nano Micro USB](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B082KFKVHG)

Comment: For whole last year there was many issues with fake CH340G and solution was installing drivers from 2022 at latest (it got broken around jan/feb 23) and disabling auto update for drivers in windows update. It had slightly different symptoms, but it could get another update